Quest 3 controllers not registering in A-Frame Immersive
This feels like a question that must have an obvious answer, as I have found no one else who seems to have this problem, but as I was attempting to work on an A-Frame project I was really confused why I couldn't get my controllers to give me movement in Immersive.  After beating my head against the wall for a while I decided to go look at working examples and see what I was doing wrong.  In every A-Frame project I went to, the controllers did not work.  Even in Stemkoski's Quest Controller Data example. There was nothing.
I feel like there must be a setting or other strange condition I'm missing, but I'm at a loss.  Any ideas?
I tried factory resetting the Quest 3. I expected that might resolve the issue if I had a setting wrong somewhere, but it didn't work. I tried a different Quest Headset, a Quest 2, and it worked fine.  I tried other WebXR experiences, thinking that perhaps it was a browser problem, but they worked just fine. I looked at an A-Frame example which shows real time controller data, thinking that would tell me if the controllers were being registered - showed data on Quest 2, but not Quest 3.

Make sure you're using A-Frame 1.5.0. For further assistance you'll have to share code with https://glitch.com/~aframe. Best of luck
